# How to Widget test Share package using widget test

Tags: flutter, flutter-test, flutter-packages

I have an issue with trying to test [Share](https://pub.dev/packages/share) package. My code looks like this:

```
IconButton(
  key: Key('share-button'),
  icon: Icon(Platform.isAndroid ? Icons.share : CupertinoIcons.share),
  onPressed: () {
     if (activity.shareLink != null) {
      Share.share('${activity.shareLink}');
     } else {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
       SnackBar(
        content: Text('Request Error'),
       ),
      );
     }
    },
   )
```

I provided [activity.shareLink] and my test looks like this:

```
await tester.tap(find.byKey(Key('share-button')));
await tester.pump(Duration(seconds: 1));
expect(find.byType(Share), findsOneWidget);
```

And my exception is:

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FLUTTER TEST FRAMEWORK ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following TestFailure object was thrown running a test:
  Expected: exactly one matching node in the widget tree
  Actual: _WidgetTypeFinder:<zero widgets with type "Share" (ignoring offstage widgets)>
   Which: means none were found but one was expected
```

Answer (score 1):

this is how they test the package in their GitHub library, maybe you should test it this way:

```
expect(Share.share('message', subject: 'title'), completes);
```

[Github Repository share_plus](https://github.com/fluttercommunity/plus_plugins/blob/main/packages/share_plus/share_plus/example/test_driver/share_plus_e2e.dart)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but that only works with unit testing, and what I'm trying to test here is widget behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Like in many packages that use native code, widget testing of the Share functionality relies on injecting a mock implementation for the platform native part.

Usually this involves a "xyzPlatform" class that exposes a static `instance` field linking to the implementation for the current platform. In the case of Share (Plus) this would be `SharePlatform.instance`.

Below is the common recipe to test invocation of such platform functionality using your favourite mocking library:

1. Add the package containing the "Platform" interface as a *dev* dependency to the project. (Convention is to name such a package "xxx_platform_interface", and you can find the name as one of the dependencies of the package in [Pub.dev](https://pub.dev).)
2. Declare a mock class for the appropriate "Platform" class using `with MockPlatformInterfaceMixin` to mark it as a platform interface.
3. Create an instance of the platform mock within the test.
4. Use this mock as the platform implementation during the test by assigning it to the static `instance` field of the appropriate "Platform" class.
5. Mock the behaviour for the method you expect to be invoked (if necessary).
6. Perform the interaction with the appropriate widgets using the `WidgetTester` instance.
7. Verify if the expected invocation has taken place.